# Varchar Overflowed an Int Column

Tags: sql-server, join, query, errors, type-conversion

I am having an error with the following query:

```
SELECT scp.phone, scp.extension, scf.fax, sce.email
  FROM supplier_contacts AS sc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier_contact_phone AS scp
       ON sc.contact_id = scp.contact_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier_contact_fax AS scf
       ON sc.contact_id = scf.contact_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier_contact_email AS sce
       ON sc.contact_id = sce.contact_id
 WHERE sc.contact_id = 184
```

I am trying to grab the contact information for a specific contact in the `supplier_contacts` table (yes id 184 exists within the table).

The error I am getting is:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> The conversion of the varchar value '9051112233' overflowed an int column

In my `supplier_contact_phone` table, I have the phone numbers stored without formatting as `VARCHAR(15)`.  I've tried searching on here for some help, but I am not sure what my issue is or how to fix it.

I don't understand why I am getting this error at all, because my data types **do** match.  `contact_id` is an INT column in every single table

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: Is this the complete SQL batch you're executing? Could a statement before or after this one be the cause? I agree that there's nothing that would obviously require conversion in what we see. If it turns out one of the "tables" is actually a view, or this is part of a `UNION` statement, that would change the picture, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple repro:

```
create table a(id int)
create table b(id varchar(20))

insert into a(id) values (1)
insert into b(id) values ('9051112233')

select *
from a
join b
 on a.id = b.id
```

`int` has a higher [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) than `varchar`.  So the comparison will convert the `varchar` to an `int`.  If you want you can force the conversion to happen the other way. EG:

```
SELECT scp.phone, scp.extension, scf.fax, sce.email
  FROM supplier_contacts AS sc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier_contact_phone AS scp
       ON cast(sc.contact_id as varchar(15)) = scp.contact_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier_contact_fax AS scf
       ON sc.contact_id = scf.contact_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier_contact_email AS sce
       ON sc.contact_id = sce.contact_id
 WHERE sc.contact_id = 184
```

Obviously it would be better to have the data types match in the first place.